# why dark matter causes gravity as its property is different than ordinary matter?

Tags: gravity

For temperature, pressure, vacuum, electomegnetisum etc. there is only one   physical phenomena responsible(it can not be created by other means). Is it true? If so, why dark matter causes gravity as its property is different than ordinary matter?

Comment: You might want to try this question on physics.SE; dark-matter even has its own tag there, with 555 questions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dark-matter

Comment: This question is not on-topic for this site. As noted by the comment by @DrSheldon, it is on-topic elsewhere in the StackExchange network. That said, there are two known forms of dark matter, neither of which resolves the galactic rotation problem. These are neutrinos and weakly charged black holes. A neutrino coming directly toward the Earth is most likely to pass completely through the Earth, emerging on the opposite side. The same applies to a high velocity, smallish black hole (although it would emerge a bit more massive).

Comment: There are four known interactions: gravitation, the weak interaction, electromagnetism, and the strong interaction. Neutrinos do not interact with electrical charge or with color charge. That leaves just gravitation and the weak interaction. Neutrinos are very hard to detect. Every second, about 100 billion solar neutrinos pass through the tip of your finger.